# How to set Yes & No button actions on hyperlink in SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('courseRegistration', $item->cor_id) }}" class="btn btn-info" id="custombtn">
     Register
</a>
```

Then I added this to show a Sweetalert message with **Yes** and **No** buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', '#custombtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
    {
        title: "Alert!",
        text: "You have an active Wallet, do you wish to pay the price with the active Wallet?",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm.value === true) {
            // go to the href route
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see I want to say: if user clicked on the **Yes** button, goto href route and if not, stays on the page (`return false`).

So the question is, how can I redirect user to `href="{{ route('courseRegistration', $item->cor_id) }}"`, if he clicks on **Yes** button?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.location.href = "YOURLINKHERE"` to redirect to another page after checking if isConfirm.value is set (you dont have to check for true, since the cancel Button doesn't return isConfirm.value)

Comment: How to add `{{ route('courseRegistration', ['course'=>$item->cor_id,'wallet'=>$user_wallet->id]) }}` instead of `"YOURLINKHERE"` properly?

Comment: you should have some kind of url for your route like https://example.com/courseRegistration, just replace YOURLINKHERE with the url